# Why does my component render before setState?

Tags: reactjs, render, setstate

EDIT - Added `render` function

I've been fighting with this for weeks now. I want to create two lists that are displayed in a dashboard, both using data from an API. If I create a const with dummy data, the lists are displayed as required. However, when I try to use the same code to display information coming from my API, I get one list displayed before I have set the state condition calling for the render. At one point I didn't get either list displaying so I'm overjoyed to be making some progress at least. If anyone can assist with pointing out what I'm doing wrong, I would be very grateful!

```
async componentDidMount() {
    let data = {
      firstName: sessionStorage.getItem('cwsFirstName'),
      surname: sessionStorage.getItem('cwsSurname'),
      email: sessionStorage.getItem('cwsUser'),
      role: sessionStorage.getItem('cwsRole'),
      type: sessionStorage.getItem('cwsType'),
      storeId: sessionStorage.getItem('cwsStoreId'),
      clientId: sessionStorage.getItem('cwsClient')
    };

    let user = [];
    user.push(data);
    await this.setState({ user: user });
    const client = data.clientId;

    // start with extracting the services from the db
    const clientservices = await this.mysqlLayer.Get(`/admin/clientservices/${client}`);
    //console.log('clientservices: ', clientservices);

    let workzones = [
      {
        worklist: 'Queues',
        task: 'list_all'
      },
      {
        worklist: 'Today',
        task: 'list_today'
      }
    ];

    // loop through services to populate worklists
    let loopCount = 0;
    clientservices.forEach(async service => {
      let workspace = service.service;
      let type = service.type;

      let workspaces = [];

      // loop through the workzones
      workzones.forEach(async workzone => {
        //console.log('workzone: ', workzone);
        let worklists = [];
        let task = workzone.task;
        let records = await this.mysqlLayer.Get(`/${type}/${workspace}/${task}/${client}`);
        //console.log('records: ', records);

        let statusArr = [];
        records.forEach(async record => {
          //console.log('currentStatus: ', record.currentStatus);
          statusArr.push(record.currentStatus);
        });

        let completeWorklist = statusArr.filter(this.onlyUnique);

        let statusList = [];
        if (completeWorklist.length > 0) statusList = this.filterWorklists(workspace, completeWorklist);

        let items = [];
        statusList.forEach(async element => {
          //console.log('element: ', element);
          let count = 0;
          records.forEach(async record => {
            if (record.currentStatus === element) {
              ++count;
            }
          });
          items.push({
            item: element,
            count: count
          });
          //console.log('items: ', items);
        }); // end of worklist loop *******************************

        worklists.push({
          worklist: workzone.worklist,
          items: items
        });
        //console.log('worklists: ', workzone, worklists, moment(new Date()).format('HH:mm:sss'));
        //console.log('worklists: ', workzone, worklists, moment(new Date()).milliseconds());

        await this.setState({
          records: records,
          type: type,
          worklists: [...this.state.worklists, ...worklists]
        });

        ++loopCount;
        console.log('loopCount: ', loopCount);

        //console.log('this.state.worklists: ', this.state.worklists, moment(new Date()).milliseconds());
        let tempWorklists = this.state.worklists;
        //console.log('tempWorklists: ', tempWorklists, moment(new Date()).milliseconds());

        workspaces.push({
          workspace: workspace,
          worklists: tempWorklists
        });


      }); // end of workzone loop *******************************


      //console.log('2 workspaces: ', workspaces);

      await this.setState({
        //loading: false,
        //workspaces: [...this.state.workspaces, ...workspaces]
        workspaces: workspaces
        //workspaces: workspacesConst
      });
      //console.log('this.state.workspaces: ', this.state.workspaces, moment(new Date()).milliseconds());

      await this.setState({
        //loading: false,
        //workspaces: [...this.state.workspaces, ...workspaces]
        workspaces: workspaces
        //workspaces: workspacesConst
      });
      //console.log('this.state.workspaces: ', this.state.workspaces, moment(new Date()).milliseconds());

    }); // end of workspace loop *******************************

    // Should be good to render now
    //if (this.state.worklists.length > 1)
    await this.setState({ loading: false });
    //this.forceUpate();

  }

render() {

    if (this.state.loading) {
      return (
        <div>Loading...</div>
      );
    } else {

      const workspace = this.state.workspaces.map((workspace, idx) =>
      //const workspace = workspaces.map((workspace, idx) =>
        <div key={idx} className="card border-light mb-3" style={{padding: "20px"}}>
          {console.log('render workspace: ', workspace.worklists, moment(new Date()).milliseconds())}
          <Workspace
            key={idx}
            records={this.state.records}
            workspaces={workspace}
            type={this.state.type}
            user={this.state.user}
          />
        </div>
      );

      return (
        <div className="container">
          <div className="cols-12">
            <Welcome user={this.state.user}/>
            {workspace}
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

[image: Render console log]
As you can see, the render happens before `this.state.loading` is set to 'false'. Surely it should only render after that?

Comment: The render will always be execute once you update the state using setState.
After the first iteration you are updating the state of workspaces, which will force rerendering.
Can not help more without seeing the render function.

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to include `render`. I have edited my question now to add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not how `setState` and react life cycle works.
Actually each time you called `setState` react will automatically call `render` method.
So in your `componentDidMount` you are calling setState multiple times. so it will render your component that many times. and render your workspaces.
It will not stop until your last call to `setState` to set loading false.
I suggest you to use `spinner` of `progressbar` or something like that to show while `loading` is `true` and once it became `false` you can show `workspaces`.
and one more note here is `setState` is `asynchronous` but `await` will not work with `setState` because it does not return any `promise`.
More about react lifecycle -

- https://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/
- https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: I honestly didn't know that `await` wouldn't work with `setState` but now that I do, it makes a lot more sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

There were two issues here which resulted in my problem:

1. `await` doesn't work with `setState` as pointed out by Sagar - I didn't know this before
2. `await` with a function that returns a Promise does work (e.g. API calls) but the code will continue running until the Promise is fulfilled. I knew this but hadn't quite realised what it meant for the sequence I was trying to create.

I figured this out by adding a console.log to each and every line in my code to see what was happening when. What I came to realise is the line that calls for the API extract is what was causing the issue:

`` let records = await this.mysqlLayer.Get(`/${type}/${workspace}/${task}/${client}`); ``

My code was running all the way through and updating the state to say it was done because the `await` meant it was running sections in parallel.

I haven't fixed the code to work yet but wanted to let others know in case they have similar problems.